# GLTF Iridescent material

Tags: gltf

Fairly new to Blender but I am trying to achieve this Irridecent effect that can be exported to GLTF format.

[image: holo]

Comment: Hello and welcome. What is your question? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: The question was, can iridescence be exported to glTF from Blender?  And the answer is, no... not yet.  Khronos is working on an Iridescence extension for glTF that is currently [open for public feedback](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/2027).  Once the extension is approved, efforts will likely follow to add support for it to the existing glTF exporter for Blender.

Comment: (And as always, nothing I write here constitutes a promise of timing or availability.  But once the extension is approved, open source contributions are welcome as well.)